# Hide/Unhide inactive Windows in XFCE?

Tags: linux, xfce

I'm using XFCE Desktop Environment and long time ago I was playing with setting and find some option that hide inactive windows and shows Desktop wallpaper directly behind my transparent terminal and discard opened windows. Now, I lost this options and I want to return to its default where can I find this options?

Comment: Do you mean inactive windows are hidden _in general,_ or do you mean they're invisible _through your terminal specifically_?

Comment: it was in general and I found the solution thanks, but can I do it for terminal specifically? I want to take an advantage of nice wallpaper with transparent terminal